# After Upgrading from Alfresco 4.2 to 5.2, Transformation is not working for .TIF Image files

Tags: imagemagick, alfresco, libreoffice, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I have migrated one Application from Alfresco 4.2 version to Alfresco 5.2 version.
But after up-gradation Image preview is not displaying for any file and Transformation is not working.

Console Logs:-----

> 2018-02-02 08:58:46,022  INFO  [repo.jscript.ScriptNode] [http-apr-8080-exec-25] Unable to create thumbnail 'doclib' for image/tiff as no transformer is currently available.
>
> 2018-02-02 08:59:10,076  WARN  [jcms.transform.TesseractOCRTransformer] [http-apr-8080-exec-45] Command options did not appear to contain ImageMagick setting for monochrome, cannot invoke Tesseract.

Can anyone please help with this, or any work around to solve this issue.

your valuable reply will be really appreciated.

For more details about issue, please find attached screen-shot.[image]

Comment: Do you have some logs to show us ?

Comment: @Akah I have added the console logs in the question, please let me know if you have any workaround for this issue.. Thanks

Comment: `Command options did not appear to contain ImageMagick setting for monochrome` This seems to indicate the tool you are using does not have a call to Imagemagick's -monochrome function.

Comment: @fmw42 do you have any solution in your mind for this type of issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the tools you are using and to what degree they make use of ImageMagick. I would suggest you check with the developers of those tools and make sure that you are not just making a mistake in your syntax when calling it and to find out if they do or do not support Imagemagick's -monochrome. Perhaps their syntax has changed in the upgraded version.

Answer (score 0):

In the Alfresco Community 5.2 on Windows the ImageMagick install is borked. I found a workaround:

1. Install ImageMagick from the developer site
   https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php
2. Edit the **alfresco-global.properties** found in C:\alfresco-community\tomcat\shared\classes

Change the img.root value to point to your fresh installation, like this:

```
img.root=C:\\PROGRA~1\\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16
```

3. Restart the alfresco server

**NOTE:** You will see this in the logs before:

```
err:        convert.exe: RegistryKeyLookupFailed `CoderModulesPath' @ error/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/670.
convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `GIF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/509.
```

Afterwards that error will not be present in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `setenv.bat file` that sets up some Imagemagick related environment variables. I suspect they're missing from the build that you have, either by yours or Alfresco's mistake.

After you installed Imagemagick separately, that installation simply took care of these variables.

They go something like this:

> MAGICK_HOME="/srv/alfresco-3.4.a/common"
>
> MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH="/srv/alfresco-3.4.a/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.5.1/config:/srv/alfresco-3.4.a/common/share/ImageMagick-6.5.1/config"
>
> MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH="/srv/alfresco-3.4.a/common/lib/ImageMagick-6.5.1/modules-Q16/coders"